# How to minify JavaScript files that have changed (and only them) when building (aka duplicate items after adding "ItemGroup" to csproj)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, buildaction

I've added the following code to my .csproj in order to minify the JS files that have changed when building the project:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <MSBuild Targets="CheckAndMinifyJS" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" />
</Target>
<ItemGroup>
  <JS Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CheckAndMinifyJS" Inputs="@(JS)" Outputs="@(JS->'$(ProjectDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).min.js')">
  <AjaxMin JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".min.js" />
</Target>
<UsingTask TaskName="AjaxMin" AssemblyFile="..\..\ThirdParty\AjaxMinTask.dll" />
```

This works great, but it has a side effect: when you look at the project in Visual Studio (2015), all the JS files appear duplicated (same path, but different build action):

[image: Duplicate items]

I would like to avoid having the item with "JS" build action appearing in the project. How can I do that?

Please note that the several developers are working with the project, so any proposed solution should be contained within the .csproj or the solution (eg: it is not acceptable to ask all developers to modify their registry to change the default build action for JS files).

Comment: Have you tried giving the Item `JS` a different name? Maybe '`JS` is 'reserved' by VS..

Comment: @stijn yes I did try that... Whatever name I put, I get my files to appear in the project with a Build Action of the same name

Comment: I think my problem is that all my JavaScript files have already been added to the csproj as "Content". Adding a new "JS" item that targets them must be causing them to appear again as "JS". I probably need to be able to change my Inputs and Outputs in the "CheckAndMinifyJS" target so that I don't have to use that "JS" item.

Comment: ... or I need to make sure Visual Studio doesn't add my JavaScript files with "Build action = Content"

Comment: Could you please describe what is the desired set of build actions you want to see for your *.js items within the VS? JS, Content, or both .. ? I hope I understand correctly that you want to see each *.js file only once within the solution explorer, I just don't know what set of build actions you desire.

Comment: Also, if I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve then you may want to reconsider your approach and rather base it on [the following article](http://encosia.com/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: Can you please run your build with /verbosity:diag and post output log somewhere ?

Comment: @MichalHosala, thanks for the link, but I'm trying to move away from the post build event (which I have already put in place). The reason is that the project (a web application) contains hundreds of JS files, and I don't want the minification to occur each time you build unless the content of the file has changed (that why I'm using Inputs and Outputs  in my target). Regarding your other question, I don't mind which Build Action appears when you open the project in Visual, I just don't want to see 2 times the same JS file.

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak: are you looking for something in particular? Not sure what you want to see. The behaviour I'm describing is consistent with what's in the csproj. Just trying to amend that csproj to file another solution to work around these duplicates.

Comment: I want to see who is adding that files with action JS. As I haven't used AjaxMin task before - I can't guess what is there but I suspect that it's AjaxMin task performing that inclusion. Want to see conditions evaluation checks  that happens inside

Comment: That's the code I posted, and in particular those 3 lines:
<ItemGroup>
  <JS Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.js" />
</ItemGroup>

Comment: @GyumFox - I know this question is old, but if you are able to, kindly check whether my answer gets you the VS behavior you were seeking.

Comment: @weir Thanks so much for answering. I will definitely have a look, but I can't tell you when (I switched to another project). I'll put a comment on the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide your `ItemGroup` from Visual Studio, move it into an intermediate `Target`. In addition to that change, the following code filters the existing `Content` items rather than recursing the file system again. This ensures you don't pick up extraneous `.js` files (for example intermediate output files in `obj\`, or `.min.js` files generated by your script but not explicitly added to the project).

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Targets="CheckAndMinifyJS" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="GetJSItems" BeforeTargets="CheckAndMinifyJS">
    <ItemGroup>
      <JS Include="@(Content)" Condition=" '%(Extension)' == '.js' " />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CheckAndMinifyJS" Inputs="@(JS)" Outputs="@(JS->'$(ProjectDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).min.js')">
    <AjaxMin JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".min.js" />
  </Target>
  <UsingTask TaskName="AjaxMin" AssemblyFile="..\..\ThirdParty\AjaxMinTask.dll" />
```

Comment: This seems to work very well! +1. I'll do a few more tests before accepting the answer. Thanks!